# Firefox mouseover errors after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, firefox, 22.04

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, Firefox doesn't activate menus or cursor shapes on *mouseover* and I need to perform a click for Firefox to respond to these events.

After upgrade I was unable to update Firefox and finally I had to do a complete removal en re-install, but after reinstalling, the problem persists.

(I reinstalled Firefox from the Software center).

Other related errors: for example, when I select text on a page, the text isn't highlighted until I release the mouse, so it's quite uncomfortable as you don't know for sure which text is selected.

Comment: Have the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04.1. Thought I could solve it by installing Firefox in the non-Snap style but this was wrong and this issue also occurred there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue since few weeks on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 and Firefox 108. Today I tried different version of Firefox and on the latest beta (109.0-1) the issue still occurs, but surprisingly it seems that the nightly version (110.0a1) fixes the problem. Usually the issue occurred after maximum 15 minutes, now I'm testing it for few hours already and everything still works fine.

It would be nice if someone else could also check if the newest version solves the problem for him. If you manage the installation by snap, you can update it by changing the channel:

```
sudo snap refresh firefox --channel=latest/edge
```

Comment: So far it seems to be working, does this mean in future versions it will be solved in the standard version/channel?

Answer (score 4):

There's a bugticket for Firefox ([Bugticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1774531)).

If you force Firefox to use Wayland by adding `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` to `~/.profile` hover should work as expected.