# Mouse hover events broken on Firefox

Tags: firefox, 22.10

I have an issue, which I saw only on Firefox : after some time (or some event which I haven't identified yet), Firefox does not react to my mouse movement events

meaning :

- when hovering over an HTML item, it does not highlight/change appearance even if it is supposed to do so,
- when hovering over a clickable item, the cursor does not change,
- when hovering over selectable text, the cursor does not change,
- tooltips do not appear,
- etc ...

if I trigger other GUI events (if I *click*, or if I *press a keyboard key*), then the GUI reacts (cursor changes, tooltips appear, animations get triggered ...), a bit as if, by handling that other event, firefox realized "oh, the cursor is actually there", but with no external event, my `mousenter`/`mouseleave` events seem to be ignored, or stalled.

Running Ubuntu 22.10 (kinetic), and regular firefox snap install (my current version: 108.0.1).

Does anyone have a similar issue ?

---

[edit] I opened an issue on launchpad, if any of you care to bring more details to it:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/2006468

Comment: Annoys me for a few weeks already, using the binary package (not snap) on 22.04, happens since updating to 108.0. Did not find any other post mentioning it last time I searched and thought it was a my-computer issue, now it looks like an our-computers issue …

Comment: Not sure if related, I have DisplayLink drivers installed.

Comment: Same issue. When I switched from Wayland to Xorg it went away..

Comment: @L3viathan: did you switch back to Xorg even on 22.10 ? I have several colleagues running firefox on Ubuntu 22.10 and they don't have this issue.

Comment: @LeGEC I'm actually on 22.04 LTS, but other than that it's the exact same issue.

Comment: I have the exact same symptoms running Firefox 109 on Arch Linux under Wayland. So it's definitely not Ubuntu-related.

Comment: Did 112.0(.2) fix it? I have not had the problem for quite some time now.

Comment: … nope. Just got too used to it. Still in 112.0.2

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster: meh ... sorry to hear that. Did you try the `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` suggest in the answer ? I hadn't returned to this question, but it works for me.

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, did not change anything, but I'm not sure if the variable is applied correctly when I start Firefox, I'm using a shortcut from the desktop environment. I'll test again with Firefox started from command line.

Comment: Pretty sure i've been having the same (intermittent) experience all these months (and still happening with the latest Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid,Gnome 44.5, Wayland.) One additional note though:  If i hover over an element that should have a response, *and then i press the control key*, the interaction works as expected.  (Like pressing control tells Firefox to check the mouse.)  It almost feels like an accessibility feature that gets toggled mysteriously.)  Is this the same bug for other people, is pressing control to activate the expected tooltip, dropdown etc a 'workaround' for you also?

Comment: Reading comprehension update, the original post makes exactly the same point about pressing control or any other key to trigger it, yeah i have exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is also discussed in [Firefox mouseover errors after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435846/firefox-mouseover-errors-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04)

My suggested solution is the following:

> There's a bugticket for Firefox ([Bugticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1774531)).
> If you force Firefox to use Wayland by adding `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` to `~/.profile` hover should work as expected.

Comment: tryed and that did not work for me, ff112, ubuntu22.04

Comment: after adding : `export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` to my `~/.profile` my problem disappeared. So this is (in my experience) a valid workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that worked reliably for me was to add it to the desktop launcher. Exporting it globally didn't seem to work.

Copy the desktop shortcut to *~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop*

Then edit it and add "*env MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1*" in all the *Exec=* lines.
Example:

```
Exec=firefox %u
```

becomes

```
Exec=env MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 firefox %u
```

To verify that it worked, look for Window Protocol in about:support. It must say wayland. If it says xwayland, then you missed a step.

A note from past experience: if Firefox is pinned to your dashboard you have to un-pin it, restart it and pin it back in order to pick up the changes.

Sources:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Firefox#Wayland
- [Firefox mouseover errors after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435846/firefox-mouseover-errors-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanations. In my setup however, adding `export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` to my `~/.profile` worked.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on fedora, so it is was probably different. I can see the variable set when starting a new shell, but it does not change the "Window Protocol" in about:support. I was only able to get it right after editing the .desktop file.